# Python - Syntax Error for valid statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, syntax-error

I don't have experience in Python, but I still see no issues with these statements that I'm getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` for. These errors are given when trying to run a Python script I downloaded from GitHub.

Statement (1):

```
if len(sys.argv) <> 3:
print "Usage: python program.py inFile.vbs outFile.vbs"
sys.exit()
```

Error (1):

```
File "program.py", line 1
if (len(sys.argv) <> 3):
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Statement (2):

```
if exp == 0:
    print "Char " + str(char) + " -> " + str((range+char)) + "-" + str(range)
    return str((range+char)) + "-" + str(range)
```

Error (2):

```
File "program.py", line 2
print "Char " + str(char) + " -> " + str((range+char)) + "-" + str(range)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It is probably because you are using python 3.x and you are trying to launch a script written for python 2.x

Comment: `<>` is deprecated, use `!=` instead. Which Python version  is this?

Comment: And the second error is because the syntax for python3 is `print("Char" + str(char))` while this code, written in python2, uses `print "Char" + str(char)`, so the parentheses are missing. Use the (deprecated) Python2 ;)

Comment: In Python 3.6 `f'Char {char} -> {range + char}-{range}'` would do with a little more beauty.

Comment: @Xatyrian That was it! I just put the script into pythonconverter.com and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You downloaded code that was written for Python 2. You are running Python 3.
You might be able to make it work with Python 3 but there will likely be more problems.

To solve your shown problems:

1. Replace all occurrences of `<>` with `!=`
2. Add parenthesis to all `print` statements. For example:

   `print("Char " + str(char) + " -> " + str((range+char)) + "-" + str(range))`
3. Be prepared to do more work. ;)

Alternatively, search for a different library that supports Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run the script, try [Python 2](https://www.anaconda.com/download/). Else the comments above contain a lot of tips how to rewrite the code for Python 3.

Comment: Well, comments are transient and frequently get cleared up. If you want to bundle this into an answer, you should explicitly state the points that have been made.